# Creating unifired profiles for Facebook and Linkedin Friends

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, social-networking, linkedin-api

My goal is to allow a user to:

1. connect his facebook and linkedin profile
2. Find and unify his friends/connections from both networks. (So that a friend on both networks would appear as one)

The best and safest way to find duplicates is if users have the same email address.

However, both [Facebook's Graph search](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/email-permissions/) and [Linkedin's API](http://developer.linkedin.com/thread/2692), won't give you the email of a user's friends/connections.

**First question**: Is this 100% correct or is there a hack for this?

**Second question**: Assuming there is no other way, How would you recommend I unify profiles? I don't want to risk finding duplicated based on name's because they are not reliable.

Comment: It is quite rare to have two friends with same names. You cannot get the email address but I think comparing name should be the best option.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a straight solution, you need the user's help.

Google does the same in Android, kinda like

```
John Smith Mobile
    facebook/john.smith?    [✓]
    twitter/john.smith?     [ ]
    LinkedIn/s.johnnathan?  [✓]
                         [Merge Checked Btn]
```